# fourier transform of $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

**Question**

If i have that the fourier transform of $f(x)$ is $\widehat{f(k)}$, then what is the fourier transform of $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$? **Problem 7.2.8 Chapter 7 Introduction to partial differential equation Peter Olver**

I know that this can be done with covolution, but the text book that i'm following has not introduced yet how to work with covolution, so i wonder how to answer the question without covolution, could someone helpe me please

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the specific problem you want to solve? Can you update the question with more info about $f(x)$?

Comment: the first line is the question that i have, the problem does not give me more information about $f(x)$

Comment: I wonder if the intent is to use integration by parts?

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=f(x)/x$, and suppose that $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is of Schwartz class.  Then $g$ is Schwartz, and $\widehat g$ is well defined.  We want to write $\widehat g$ in terms of $\widehat f$.  To do this, let us differentiate the equation $\widehat g(\xi)=\int e^{-i\xi x}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ by $\xi$:

$$
\widehat g'(\xi)=-i\int e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx=-i\widehat f(\xi).
$$

Note that differentiation is permissible since $g$ is Schwartz.  So, by the fundamental theorem of calculus combined with $\widehat g(-\infty)=0$, we obtain:

$$
\widehat g(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\xi \widehat f(\eta)d\eta/i,
$$

i.e. $\widehat g$ is the anti-derivative of $\widehat f$.

Answer (score 0):

You get
$$
\begin{gather}
\int \frac1xf(x)e^{-i2\pi kx} dx = \\ 
\left[\frac 1x f(x) e^{-i2\pi kx} \frac1{-i2\pi k} \right] - \frac1{-i2\pi k}\int \frac{f'(x)x - f(x)}{x^2}e^{-i2 \pi kx} dx = \\ 
-\frac1{-i2\pi k} F(f'(x)/x) + \frac1{-i2\pi k}F(f(x)/x^2) + \left[\frac 1x f(x) e^{-i2\pi kx} \frac1{-i2\pi k} \right]
\end{gather}
$$
So you need more information.

Comment: Dude, line breaks.  Try the `align` environment in MathJax.

Comment: Are you considering it to be unreadable? I consider it to be highly readable, but you are welcome to suggest edit. @tilper

Comment: It's readable now but I still recommend looking into the `align` environment when you get a chance.  [Example here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323712/let-fx-6-operatornamearcsec2x-find-fx/2323722#2323722).